# Array pushes data fetched from an api twice

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await, fetch

I'm making a call to an api and I'm using async/await. I'm pushing the response data to a global array, but for some reason it is pushing it twice. I'm making two fetch requests, receiving the response, pushing it to an array, and then console logging the data array. How can I prevent it from pushing the data to the array twice?

```
 var data = [];
const getData = async () => {
  const f1_data = await fetch(url + countryOne.value)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      var index = result.length - 1;
      var confirmed = result[index].Confirmed;
      textOne.textContent = result[index].CountryCode + " TOTAL CASES : " + confirmed;
      data.push(confirmed);
      console.log(data);
    })

  const f2_data = await fetch(url + countryTwo.value)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((result) => {
      var index = result.length - 1;
      var confirmed = result[index].Confirmed;
      textTwo.textContent = result[index].CountryCode + " TOTAL CASES : " + confirmed;
      data.push(confirmed);
      console.log(data);
    })
};
getData();
```

**Expected output**
Example: 56789, 89768
**Output**
56789, 56789, 89768, 89768

Comment: Quick note, using `then` with async/await defeats the purpose of using async/await in the first place.

Comment: Could you please explain why?

Comment: where is Data defined in first place?

Comment: @Love2Code it's like wearing a belt *and* suspenders. It doesn't take both to keep your pants up. Pick one.

Comment: @GermanFaller Edited

Comment: @JaredSmith Im using belt and suspender XD. @Love2Code what is the output from first ```console.log```

Comment: The first output will be whatever is fetched from the api, but it'll push to the array TWICE. So if the api returns 678, it will push it to the array 2 times

Comment: so, the fist log is ```56789, 56789``` and the second one is ```56789, 56789, 89768, 89768```. Right?

Comment: Yeah that's right

Comment: Qick note: to get the last element in array maybe you want use ```const last = result.slice(-1).pop()```

Comment: Yeah If I don't an answer I'll probably just get the first and last items in the array with slice XD

Comment: if you log your ```confirmed``` variable before push, what do you get?

Comment: It's still the same

Comment: what are you storing in f1_data and f2_data, void?

Comment: I can't Help anymore I need to see the big picture

Comment: hm that's fine, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other suggested, since you are using `aysnc` and `await`, might as well get rid of the `.then()` flow.

It seems like your getData() has been called multiple times, it is unsafe to keep `data` array outside of your getData function block. You might want to do something like this: (takes few seconds to get the api data..)

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const url = 'https://api.covid19api.com/country/'
  const query = '?from=2020-12-31T00:00:00Z&to=2021-01-01T00:00:00Z';
  let data = [];
  const f1_data = await fetch(`${url}singapore${query}`);
  const f1_json = await f1_data.json();
  data.push(f1_json[0].Confirmed);

  const f2_data = await fetch(`${url}malaysia${query}`);
  const f2_json = await f2_data.json();
  data.push(f2_json[0].Confirmed);

  return data;
};

const logData = async () => {
  let data = await getData();
  console.log(data);
}
logData();
```

return the data from your async getData function.